# Passing parameters into app component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

How do I feed static data to my app component? I would like to use the data during component initialization, a bit like `ngInit` in Angular 1.x

This is what I've tried:

**MyView.cshtml**

```
<some-viewing-app [workflows]="@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Workflows)"></some-viewing-app>
```

*or*

```
<some-viewing-app workflows="@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Workflows)"></some-viewing-app>
```

**SomeViewingAppComponent.ts**

```
export interface IWorkflowMap {
  [id: number]: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'some-viewing-app',
  providers: [...],
  template: `...`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input()
  workflows: IWorkflowMap;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.leadApiService.workflows = this.workflows; // == undefined! :(
  }
}
```

I've also tried reading the workflows from the constructor with the same result. I would prefer this solution over fetching static with AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I "solved" it by using the *ElementRef* and the *dataset* property.

*View.cshtml*

```
<app data-workflows="@Json.Encode(ViewBag.Workflows)"></app>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(rootElement: ElementRef) {
        workflows = JSON.parse(rootElement.nativeElement.dataset['workflows']);
    }
}
```